# android limit textview to 2 lines

Tags: android

in my android app i have an textview with maxLines = 2
i would like to realize, that the user can only write into 2 lines. a fix value for max length is not a solution. i have to be dynamic.

i would like to try this with an onkeylistener. but there are some problems.

```
txtView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.e("-->", "Key");
        return false;
    }
});
```

if i write some letters in this textview - the log "key" will not shown.
any ideas ?

Comment: for example, what leters does not show you the log "key"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check changes in `TextView` use this:

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            s.append("A");

        }
    });
```

and for number of lines use:

```
android:maxLines=2
```

and

```
android:minLines=1 // the minimum number of lines
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:textSize="10sp" />
```

`android:maxLines="2"` should help you

follow as @Loolooii has said and for textview use above